# how to add a git non-android library project as a sub module, to android project

Tags: android, git-submodules

I am working on project were I have to initialize this repo https://github.com/livekit/protocol as submodule in my android project. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

First clone the Android project into your local system.

```
git clone https://github.com/username/repo-name
```

Then using the `git submodule add` command, add the URL of the submodule

```
git submodule add https://github.com/livekit/protocol
```

Then execute the following commands:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Commit message"
git push origin master
```

In the last command replace `master`with the name of branch you are working with.